# Proving convergence of a sequence that is defined in two parts.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have the sequence $a_n =  \begin{cases} \frac {1}{n} ; n<1000 \\ \frac {1}{n^2} ; n\ge1000 \end{cases} $

I have to prove that this sequence converges to 0 using the definition 
$\forall ε>0 : \exists N \in \mathbb N : \forall n>N: |a_n-0| < ε$

So from $|a_n-0| < ε$ I get to $N=\lceil \frac{1}{ε} \rceil$ if $ε> 10^{-6}$ and $N = \lceil \frac{1}{\sqrtε} \rceil$ if $ε\le10^{-6}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One little simplification is possible.

Let us take $N=\lceil \frac{1}{ε} \rceil$.

What happens when we pick $ε> 10^{-3}$? We have $N>1000$.

So, for all $n \geq N$:

$\left |a_{n}-0 \right |=\frac{1}{n^{2}}< \frac{1}{n}< \frac{1}{N}< \epsilon $

What if $ε< 10^{-3}$? We have $N<1000$

So, for all $n \geq N$:

If $N\leq n< 1000$: $\left |a_{n}-0 \right |=\frac{1}{n}$

If $n\geq 1000>N$: $\left |a_{n}-0 \right |=\frac{1}{n^{2}}< \frac{1}{n}< \frac{1}{N}$ again

So you actually don't have to define $N$ in two parts.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. Here is a proof using a supplementary aspect which also simplifies the approach and might be helpful.

Note the convergence behaviour of a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ does not change when changing *finitely many elements* of the sequence. Keeping this in mind the first $999$ elements of the sequence do not need special consideration.

> **Proof:** Since the convergence behaviour of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ does not change when changing finitely many values, it is sufficient to study the convergence behaviour of 
>   \begin{align*}
> (a_n)_{n\geq1000}=\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)_{n\geq 1000}
> \end{align*}
>
> We claim the sequence converges to zero:
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=0
> \end{align*}
>
> Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left|a_n-0\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n^2}-0\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n^2}\right|<\varepsilon\qquad\qquad\text{for all }\tag{1} n>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}
> \end{align*}
>   we can choose the index $N=N(\varepsilon)$ to be
>   \begin{align*}
> N=\max\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}},1000\right\}
> \end{align*}
>   to assure that 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left|a_n-0\right|<\varepsilon\qquad\qquad\qquad \forall n> N
> \end{align*}
>
> proving that $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges to zero.

Note that when using the *maximum* in $N=\max\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}},1000\right\}$ we effectively skip the first $1000$ elements of the sequence and guarantee this way the validity of the statement (1) for all $n>N$.